# CSS to change background color of sub menu only

Tags: html, css, colors, background

i am working on a website
http://healthyeatingandliving.ca/

The problem i am facing is that that i want to keep the sub menu style as light green drowndown background, and hover and if page selected background as dark green. Currently it seems it is inheriting the style for active page from the main menu .

Anyone have any ideas on what to do to fix it? Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only found this issue in http://healthyeatingandliving.ca/corporate-wellness/

[image]

### Fix

Comment out line 481 to 484 of the following stylesheet.

http://healthyeatingandliving.ca/site/wp-content/themes/twentyten/style.css

[image]

[image]

### Update to highlight active tab

Replace `#access li.current_page_item > a { ... }` with the following code -

```
#menu-main-menu > li.current_page_item > a {
    background: url(http://healthyeatingandliving.ca/site/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/leavesbig.png) no-repeat 18px 6px !important;
    color: #ffcc00 !important;
}
```

[image]

Comment: hello Win, i had tried that already. The thing is that doing that also removes background image for the items in the MAIN menu bar. The small leaf then only appears for Tabs that have sub menus under them. I hope i make sense?

Comment: How is it supposed to work? Could you post the mock-up?

Comment: I updated the current site to simon's suggestions. Everything seems to be fine but if i do chose any menu item that is in the main menu bar then it also has the green background . I would prefer that only the sub menu items have the green background and the main menu item have the leaves in front of them. The imgur link is here of what happens now if i chose any of the main menu items http://imgur.com/Qlc5EmY

Comment: Did you even try my solution? I added the screenshot.

Comment: Yes sir, i did . Updated the main site to reflect your change. As your screenshot shows , you have chosen a sub menu item ( Corporate Wellness).  If i click on any of the MAIN menu items , there is no change in them ( for example clicking on Work With Me results in there being no color change and no leaves in front of them ). I realize i am being extremely tough to work with , its just iv been pulling out my hair since morning trying to fix this and havent gotten anywhere. take a look and i think you will get what i mean.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you want to **highlight the active tab**. If so, I updated the answer.

Comment: You got it . I cannot tell you how relieved i am . If you are in Toronto I will buy you some beer :) . Thank you so much. How did you figure it out?

Comment: You are quite welcome. I use [Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/) and [Fiddler's AutoResponder](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/askie/archive/2013/01/06/how-to-use-fiddler-autoresponder-to-replay-a-fiddler-trace.aspx). The screenshot is from VisualStudio *(it happens to be that I'm working on web application)*.

Answer (score 0):

The offending style is:

```
#access li.current_page_item > a
```

(style.css, line 481)

Change this style to :

```
#access li.current_page_item > a {
background: #39b54a !important;
}
```

and it should give you what you're after.

Comment: hello Matt, doing that makes it so that the Current page item regardless of whether it is the Main menu bar has the dark green background. I just want the sub menus to have dark green background when they are the active page and the main menus to have the white background with the leaves in front of the tab. I know im being confusing but if you need further info i will clarify

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, hopefully I haven't misunderstood.
In this page, http://healthyeatingandliving.ca/recipes/breakfast/

"Breakfast" is being selected, and the sub-menu background is showing incorrectly, change your portion of [CSS line 481](http://healthyeatingandliving.ca/site/wp-content/themes/twentyten/style.css) to

```
li.current_page_item > a {
/* 
Commented out portion is what you are using now
background: url(http://healthyeatingandliving.ca/site/wpcontent/uploads/2014/03/leavesbig.png) no-repeat 18px 6px !important; 
*/
background: #39b54a; /* no need to add !important */
color: #ffcc00 !important;
}
```

I tested in "Chrome 33.0.1750.154 m", should fix your problem.

One point to note, try to avoid using `!important` while you can, because too much overriding, will cause you trouble in tracing any inheritance problem.

**Expected result:**

1. hover or selected sub-menu will have background dark green
2. normal sub-menu keep as light green

[image]

Comment: Hi simon , the solution works fine as long as i do not select any of the main menu items. If i do click on recipes directly then that item also has the green background. I just want the Sub menu to have the green background.  . and i cant figure out how to post images on here so here is the link http://imgur.com/Qlc5EmY

Comment: I see, you may try to modify the background from image to color, `...,#access ul li.current-menu-parent > a{background: #39b54a;}`, is that what you intend to do? Or You just want to have background image(the leave like icon)?

Comment: I'm thinking i need to refer to some other element to chose the sub menu items  and not li.current_page_item > a  , since referring to that chooses whichever page is active right now regardless of whether it is a sub menu item or main menu.

Comment: did you mean you want the selected main menu with "leave icon"?

Comment: Yes Sir, Take a look at the site now. If i chose any of the sub menu items it works as intended. If i choose any Main Menu item then there is no indication that it is being selected.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help. Win figured it out somehow. Your time and effort is greatly appreciated.